# custom iterator and insert_iterator

Tags: c++

I recently wrote my first custom iterator (Yay!) It's operating on top of a container (buffer), currently an std::vector buffer but should at least in theory work with any other standard container, of variable length byte encoded data. Nothing fancy. Basically what my iterator does is calculating how far to step to get to the next entry in the buffer. I'm using th std::bidirectional_iterator_tag for my iterator.

Anyway I've been testing it a bit and it works perfectly when using it for iterating and some standard operations like std:distance or std::copy.

Then I got the idea that it would be pretty neat to be able to insert new items into the buffer. How do we do that? Well I figuerd that as I now have an iterator I could use some std::insert function. Didn't find one, std::insert_iterator/std::inserter seems to be the way to go.

Well that didn't work.

```
std::vector<unsigned char> dataBuffer;
std::vector<unsigned char> otherDataBuffer;

//*Fill dataBuffer with data*

ByteCrawlerIterator<std::vector<unsigned char> > insertionPoint(dataBuffer.begin());

//*pick an insertion point (this works)*
std::advance(insertionPoint, 5);

//*this will produce a lot of really ugly and confusing compiler errors*
std::insert_iterator<std::vector<unsigned char> > insert_itr(dataBuffer, insertionPoint);

//*Well we don't get this far, but I intended to use it something like this*
std::copy(ByteCrawlerIterator(otherDataBuffer.begin()), ByteCrawlerIterator(otherDataBuffer.end()), insert_it);
```

I was under the assumption that an insertion iterator was an adapter able to work with any iterator, even custom one. But I guess that was incorrect, what do I have to do to get my custom iterator to work with std::inserter? Or am I supposed to implement a custom insert_iterator? And when we are on the topic what about the reverse_iterator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested a conversion operator to the underlaying container iterator seems to do the trick.

With that I no longer have any problems constructing an insertion_iterator:

```
std::insert_iterator<std::vector<unsigned char> > insert_itr(dataBuffer, insertionPoint);
```

And more important it actually appears to be working!

Answer (score 3):

`std::insert_iterator` is sort of an adapter, but it works with a collection, not an iterator. To do its job, it requires that the collection have an `insert` member. When you write to the `insert_iterator`, it gets translated into a call to the collection's `insert` member.

Likewise, an `std::back_insert_iterator` works with a collection that has a `push_back` member. Writing to the `back_insert_iterator` translates into a call to the collection's `push_back`.

`std::inserter` and `std::back_inserter` are just function templates to create an `insert_iterator` or `back_insert_iterator` respectively, but using type deduction so you don't need to specify the type.

Comment: Well i pretty much figured that out but can it be used with a custom iterator like I tried to do or do you have to use the iterator provided by the container, in my example I tried to build an insert_iterator from my ByteCrawler iterator. Am I not doing it right or is it not supposed to work like this?

Comment: @AcidFloppy: At least as far as I can see, what you apparently want is something like: `std::copy(ByteCrawlerIterator(otherDataBuffer.begin()), ByteCrawlerIterator(otherDataBuffer.end()), std::back_inserter(dataBuffer));` It's not apparently, however, how your `ByteCrawlerIterator` really differs from a normal `std::vector<unsigned char>::iterator`.

Comment: It's not that different and actually wraps a vector::iterator but it calculates the number of bytes to get to the next byte encoded item in the buffer, it doesn't have to be a std::vector. Each encoded item is of variable length. I'm starting to believe this is not possible, for the inserter to call the vector.insert it would need the actual buffer iterator I wrap, I guess I could always provide an accessors for the underlaying iterator... But its a bit uglier then what I intended :(